# Display fields from one model in another in Django Admin connected with a Foreignkey

Tags: django

I have two models, one for uploaded files and one for comments. I now want to display the comments in the Admin view of each uploaded file. So for example, if I upload a file TestFile1, once I click on it in the
Uploaded view in Django admin, I want to have all of the comments associated with that file. Is this possible?

```
class Uploaded(models.Model):
    objects: models.Manager()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="users")
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.description} {self.file}" 

class Comment(models.Model):
  objects: models.Manager()
  file = models.ForeignKey('Uploaded', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
  text = models.TextField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you need is to write [InlineModelAdmin for your models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

In your case, that would be something like:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

class CommentInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Comment

class UploadedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [CommentInlineAdmin]

admin.register(Uploaded, UploadedAdmin)
```